# How can i return reflected object from AppDomain Assembly.LoadFrom

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-assembly, appdomain

I need return objects, from 2 versions of dlls in one process. I'm doing this incompatible with each other, and i want to connect to 2 types of MS WHQL Servers in one process.
I'm trying use this:

```
namespace AppDomainTester
{
    public class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string pathToDll = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
            string HCKpath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToDll), @"WhqlDlls\HCK",
                @"microsoft.windows.kits.hardware.objectmodel.dbconnection.dll");
            string HLKpath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToDll), @"WhqlDlls\HLK",
                @"microsoft.windows.kits.hardware.objectmodel.dbconnection.dll");
            try
            {
                object hck;
                object hlk;
                // HCK 
                AppDomainSetup domainSetupHck = new AppDomainSetup
                {
                    PrivateBinPath = pathToDll
                };
                AppDomain domainHck = AppDomain.CreateDomain("HCK", null, domainSetupHck);
                InstanceProxy proxyHck =
                    domainHck.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(pathToDll, typeof (InstanceProxy).FullName) as InstanceProxy;
                if (proxyHck != null)
                {
                    object obj = new object();
                    hck = proxyHck.LoadLibrary(HCKpath, "tfs13-com-hck1");
                }
                //HLK
                AppDomainSetup domainSetupHlk = new AppDomainSetup
                {
                    PrivateBinPath = pathToDll
                };
                AppDomain domainHlk = AppDomain.CreateDomain("HLK", null, domainSetupHlk);
                InstanceProxy proxyHlk =
                    domainHck.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(pathToDll, typeof (InstanceProxy).FullName) as InstanceProxy;

                if (proxyHlk != null)
                {
                    object obj = new object();
                    hlk = proxyHlk.LoadLibrary(HCKpath, "tfs13-com-hck1");
                }
                //var some = domainHck.GetAssemblies();

                AppDomain.Unload(domainHck);
                AppDomain.Unload(domainHlk);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace);
            }

        }
    }

    internal class InstanceProxy : MarshalByRefObject
    {

        private object obj;

        public object LoadLibrary(string path, string controller)
        {
            Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(path);
            Type[] types = asm.GetExportedTypes();
            Type type =
                types.FirstOrDefault(
                    t =>
                        (t.FullName == "Microsoft.Windows.Kits.Hardware.ObjectModel.DBConnection.DatabaseProjectManager"));
            if (type != null)
            {
                var constructor = type.GetConstructors().Single(x => x.GetParameters().Length == 1);
                obj = constructor.Invoke(new[] {controller});
                //
                return obj;
                //
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to return `obj` from `LoadLibrary` method, but if i try `return obj;`, i recieve an exception :(
What am I doing wrong?

---

**EDIT 1**:

> Type
>   'Microsoft.Windows.Kits.Hardware.ObjectModel.DBConnection.DatabaseProjectManager'
>   in assembly 'Microsoft.Windows.Kits.Hardware.ObjectModel.DBConnection,
>   Version=1.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' is
>   not marked as serializable.

Comment: Where did you put the `return obj;` and what error did you get?

Comment: @stuartd i added this.

Comment: .. and what exception do you get?

Comment: [Exception while dynamically creating assemblies using DefineDynamicAssembly on non-current AppDomain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468157/exception-while-dynamically-creating-assemblies-using-definedynamicassembly-on-n) looks relevant

Comment: The exception is entirely normal.  An object in another appdomain is only accessible if it derives from MarshalByObject (so all methods and properties can cross the boundary) or it must be [Serializable] (so the object itself can be copied across).  Your object is neither.  You'll need to run the code that uses the object in the appdomain as well.